# How can we include meditation in our daily activities or day to day life?

Tags: meditation-practicalities, meditation-insight, meditation

Given that if a person is extremely busy & unable to give full time to meditation but wants to penetrate mind to eradicate past live impressions, how can he/she do so?

Comment: Hello Seeker and welcome to Buddhism SE. Great question. Is there two questions here, i.e. a question about *the integration of meditation into daily life* and a question regarding methods on how to *eradicate past life impressions*?

Comment: Yes. Actually, aim is to eradicate past karmas via meditation. :) @Lanka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply comes down to two words… **sati sampajanna**.  Sati is mindfulness. 
The Pali word for alertness is sampajañña. It doesn’t mean being choicelessly aware of the present, or comprehending the present. Sampajañña means being aware of what you’re doing in the movements of the body, the movements in the mind. This is why mindfulness and alertness should always be paired.

Our happiness, our lack of happiness, depends on our actions. So that’s where we focus our attention. That’s what we should keep in mind. This is called dhammanussati, keeping the Dhamma in mind. This is why the Buddha has us listen to the Dhamma, read the Dhamma. Whatever thinking that you do, it needs to be through the Dhamma.

When you create a frame of reference here in the present moment, there are lots of things you can tune in to. You can choose the body in and of itself. You can choose feelings, mental states, mental qualities in and of themselves.

Whenever your thoughts go to recollecting your past incarnations, try to get them out of your mind, as they are a-Dhamma. To be consciously forgetful in that way requires an act of mindfulness—in other words, deciding which level you’re going to tune in to while you let everything else go for the time being. Of all the sensory input that comes in at any one particular moment, you make a choice of what you’re going to pay attention to, what memories, what frame of reference you’re going to bring to that particular moment. And it’s an important mental skill to be able to shift your frame of reference as necessary.

Being mindful means being very deliberate and clear about what you bring to whatever you’re doing: what you’re going to remember, what you’re not going to remember, what you’re going to recollect, what you’re going to let go, which things are useful to recollect right now. If you wanted to, you could sit here and spend the whole hour thinking about facts that would make you totally miserable, but what does that accomplish? We’re sitting here to think about things that are useful for the mind, so remember the things that are useful for the mind, that will help it develop. As for the other voices coming in and out of the mind, listen to the ones that are helpful and ignore the ones that are not. You can be selective.

This way, mindfulness becomes a quality we can apply to everything we do. And instead of making us unable to function, it actually heightens our ability to function, because we understand the process that the mind goes through.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I commute one hour each way on a direct train to work every day.. It's surprising how silent rush hour is often (Friday evening is a slight exception!). It's not secluded in the traditional sense, but if you have some decent earphones to kill ambient sound it gets pretty comfy, and I can get on with concentrating on meditating. It's nice as well because otherwise I'd sit there wasting time mostly!

Answer (score 0):

It is meditation if we can remember the 3 refuge every second, every minute, every hour, or at least every day.

Answer (score 0):

Please read satipattana sutta. It speaks about four forms of mindfulness, which gives you the benefit of Nibbana as well.